# Program is crashing because of if statement

Tags: c++

So I have this little bit of code that's basically just supposed to compare a number that a user enters to numbers already in an array. If the number is the same it is supposed to say `"Number is valid"` and `"Invalid"` otherwise.

```
const int size=18;
int list[size]={5658845,4520125,7895122,8777541,8451277,1302850,8080152,4562555,5552012,
5050552,7825877,1250255,1005231,6545231,3852085,7576651,7881200,4581002};
bool found = false;
int userNumber;


cout<<"Enter your number: ";
cin>>userNumber;


for(int x = 0;x < 18; x++)
{
    if(list[userNumber] == list[x])
        found = true;
}
if(found)
    cout<<"The number is valid."<<endl;
else
    cout<<"The number is invalid."<<endl;

return 0;
```

yet when the if statement strikes, the program crashes. I've tried commenting it out and it works fine. I assume it's just cause I'm being a dumbass and missing something but I've been staring at this for the past hour and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What did you input to `userNumber` when you tried it?

Comment: forgot to add that part, if I input any number between 1 and 17, it's fine. But the moment I try to use 5658845 it has an issue.

Comment: I think you mean:  if(userNumber == list[x])

Comment: Well, `list[5658845]` is an out-of-bound access.

Comment: dont be hard on yourself. it's a "can't see the forest for the trees" situation. you mind looks past the seemingly valid code.

Comment: tickable answer supplied :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referencing the array with the user number as the index, where i think you simply wish to compare each list element with the actual user number.

```
if(userNumber == list[x])
```